# Twilio IVR request parameters

Tags: twilio

I am using **ExecutionCreator** to use twilio IVR call service

```
Execution execution = new ExecutionCreator(pathFlowSid, new receiverPhoneNo, new senderPhoneNo)
                    .setParameters(request.getParametersMap()) //setting request params
                    .create(twilioClient);
```

Now I want to get the status of the IVR call and this is done by using Call resource and using statusCallback parameter as given in this https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#statuscallback, but there is no way of setting request parameters on Call resource as was possible with Execution resource(please refer to code added).
Is there any way I can get both these functionalities like statusCallback as well as setting request parameters ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to get statusCallback webhooks when you place an outbound call from a Studio Flow when you trigger a new execution from the REST API? And do you specifically want the `initiated` or `ringing` statuses?

Comment: @philnash, 1. if it is possible to get statusCallback on Execution resource then I can resuse my existing code
2. if not then, I would like to use Call resource to set statusCallback but alongwith request parameter (and that is question how to add request parameter in Call resource)

Comment: Flows may not make outbound calls, or they may make multiple outbound calls, so you can’t assign a statusCallback URL. If you were able to set custom parameters when making an outbound call with the REST API, how would you use them? Where would you access them? I’m trying figure out what to suggest to you, so if you could give me more information about your use case, that would help.

Comment: @philnash, use case is, I want to know the status of the outbound IVR call whether its ringing, received etc. But in existing code we are using  ExcutionCreator, which
`request.addPostParam("Parameters", Converter.mapToJson(**parameters**));` does this and here **parameters** are nothing but `setParameters(request.getParametersMap())`. Now again according to doc on Call resource we can specify statusCallback url but didn't find anything for parameters. So if I use Call resource I may break existing functionality.

Comment: What are you using those parameters for in your existing call flow? Is there more in your Studio Flow than just an outbound call?

Comment: @philnash, those parameters gets added as a form parameters when we create Execution through sdk with **Parameters** as a key and list of values. Values are nothing but map converted JSON string.

Comment: But what are you actually using them for in the context of the call?